# AWS Certificate not working with www.example.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I have an AWS certificate configured for both www.example.com and example.com

[image]

It's used in Cloud Front as follows :

[image]

When I test my website, it's working for example.com and not for www.example.com

For `www`,  it is saying "Invalid Certificate"

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Comment: Are you sure it's serving the right certificate for www.domain.com? Is CloudFront properly configured on both?

Comment: Provide full error message not just "Invalid Certificate". Also your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. You may have a better change on [webmasters.se] or [sf] depending on the case.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek which full error message you're talking about ? There is no error message. It's just when you click on the disabled certificate icon on chrome : it says invalid certificate.